# Problems with Tuple's lifetime in rust.

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrowing

I'm trying to implement a simple parser for a byte stream.

I'm having troubles when I want to reuse a variable I declared previously,

```
fn read_data(asn_data: &mut Cursor<&[u8]>) -> Result<(u8, u8, Vec<u8>), Err> {
    let total_len = asn_data.get_ref().len();

    if total_len < 2 {
        return Err(1);
    }
    let d_type = asn_data.read_u8().unwrap();
    let d_len = asn_data.read_u8().unwrap();

    if (asn_data.position() + d_len as u64) > total_len as u64 {
        return Err(2);
    }

    let mut buf = vec![0; d_len as usize];

    match asn_data.read_exact(&mut buf) {
        Err(e) => Err(e),
        Ok(()) => Ok((d_type, d_len, buf)),
    }

}

fn parse_request(request: &[u8]) -> Option<u8> {

    if request.len() == 0 {
        return None;
    }

    let mut rdr = Cursor::new(request);
    let data_tuple = read_data(&mut rdr).unwrap();
    println!("{:02?}", data_tuple.2);

    rdr = Cursor::new(data_tuple.2.as_slice());
    let data_tuple = read_data(&mut rdr).unwrap();
    println!("{:02x?}", data_tuple.2);

    Some(1)
}
```

In the parse_request function I want to reuse rdr variable, but with the code shown above I get the next error when compiling:

> error[E0597]: `data_tuple.2` does not live long enough    -->
>   src/main.rs:80:23
>       | 80  |     rdr = Cursor::new(data_tuple.2.as_slice());
>       |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough ... 104 | }
>       | - `data_tuple.2` dropped here while still borrowed
>       |
>       = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
>
> error: aborting due to previous error

However if I write "let mut" when I use the 2nd time rdr variable, the code compiles and works fine...

```
let mut rdr = Cursor::new(data_tuple.2.as_slice());
```

I don't understand why... what I want is to reuse the variable instead to declare it again...

I tried with some examples/issues related to variable life time but I didn't get the solution for my case... and the solution I found I don't understand fully...

Comment: The easiest solution is to enable non-lexical lifetimes (or simply use the beta version of the 2018 edition).

Comment: Redeclaring `rdr` makes sure it is declared _after_ `data_tuple`, so the former can't outlive the latter.  If you reuse the variable, the declaration order is the other way around, so `rdr` is only dropped after `data_tuple`, hence the error.

Comment: Do you really have an error type called `Err`, which is in scope at the same time as the enum variant of the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not connected with tuple lifetimes, this is just the drop order.

When the variables are defined in separate `let` statements in the same scope (that is, in the same block), they will be dropped in *reverse* order. Looking at your code, we can see:

```
let mut rdr = Cursor::new(request);
let data_tuple = read_data(&mut rdr).unwrap();
```

So, `data_tuple` will be dropped *first*, while `rdr` is still alive. This is bad, because `rdr` must reference the tuple. The easiest fix will be to swap their definitions:

```
let data_tuple: (u8, u8, Vec<u8>);
let mut rdr = Cursor::new(request);
data_tuple = read_data(&mut rdr).unwrap();
```

This way, `rdr` will be dropped first, releasing the reference to `data_tuple` and letting the tuple be dropped itself.

The "fix" you mentioned works, because every `let` statement defines new variable, *even if the same name is already used*, and the existing variable is immediately forgotten. So, when you write:

```
let mut rdr = Cursor::new(request);
let data_tuple = read_data(&mut rdr).unwrap();
let mut rdr = Cursor::new(data_tuple.2.as_slice());
```

the second `rdr` is in no way connected with the first. Essentially, it's almost the same as declaring two different variables, say, `rdr` and `rdr2`, and using `rdr2` from this place until the end of function.

Comment: The data type isn't really necessary.  Just `let data_tuple;` works fine.  Rust infers the type from the later assignment.